# Correctly appending to React Native flatlist from Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to append to a Flatlist in React-Native. The new information is appended but the Flatlist rerenders and I am taken back to the top of the list when the data Prop is changed.

```
<FlatList
       data={users}
       onEndReached={(): any => loadMore()}
       onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
       keyExtractor={(item: Profile): string => item.id}
       renderItem={this.renderRow}
/>
```

The users array is passed in as a Prop from Redux.
In the Reducer, I append the new users retrieved by the API call in loadMore() as such:

```
users: state.users.concat(action.payload.users)
```

I have also tried:

```
users: [...state.users, ...action.payload.users]
```

I am assuming the Flatlist rerenders the whole array rather than append any new users to the end which causes the scroll to reset to the top. 
Am I missing something that is causing this to happen?

Comment: Are you sure your keyExtractor is correct? That's what should allow the flatlist to keep track of items and handle changes to data.

Comment: Also since the FlatList is a pure component you may want to remove all of the anonymous functions from the FlatList props in favor of stable function refs.

Comment: It wasn't quite the anonymous functions but I was rendering the Flatlist inside tabs with an anonymous function which caused the resetting, thank you for pointing me in the right direction